# Dado a determinada String abaixo, como faço para definir esta divisão?

Tags: php, string

Tenho a seguinte string:

> "Dados do Usuário: JOAQUIM DE OIVEIRA, NASCIDO
>   EM 2010, FORMADO EM: DIREITO, HOBBIE: FUTEBOL"

Como faço para dar um `explode` nessa *string* só validando o primeiro sinal de separação e a dividindo em dois ? Exemplo:

```
pedaço1="Dados do Usuário";
pedaço2="JOAQUIM DE OIVEIRA, NASCIDO EM 2010, FORMADO EM: DIREITO, HOBBIE: FUTEBOL";
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função `explode`. Veja a documentação [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php).

```
$string = "Dados do Usuário: JOAQUIM DE OIVEIRA, NASCIDO EM 2010, FORMADO EM: DIREITO, HOBBIE: FUTEBOL";
$array = explode(":", $string, 2);

// $array[0] = "Dados do Usuário"
// $array[1] = "..."
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar o [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) que é semelhante ao explode só que usa uma expressão regular.

```
$string = "Dados do Usuário: JOAQUIM DE OIVEIRA, NASCIDO EM 2010, FORMADO EM: DIREITO, HOBBIE: FUTEBOL";
preg_match("/^([^:]*:\s)(.*)/", $string, $pedacos);
echo $pedacos[2]; // "JOAQUIM DE OIVEIRA, NASCIDO EM 2010, FORMADO EM: DIREITO, HOBBIE: FUTEBOL"
```

#### Exemplo: http://ideone.com/rZDzvR

Neste exemplo vai ter uma array de 3 elementos. O primeiro é a string completa, o segundo tem só "Dados do Usuário: " e o terceiro (`$pedacos[2]`) o resto.